# Should we insert main method in class diagram

Tags: c#, class, program-entry-point, diagram

Can anybody please suggest do i have to or can i represent main method (of course static) in class diagram. I have this class (standalone code) which has everything done in main method. No class variables, no other methods and no other classes. I have already refactored the code to break in 5 different classes and already made class diagram for them. But part of my assignment requires to make a class diagram for the unrefactored code too. Please suggest.

Comment: If the main method is part of the design and the class diagram is supposed to draw a complete picture of your design then you should include it, I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I include it in my case because this is the function which initiates the application. It is not different than other functions.

Comment: So my class diagram will have nothing in attributes, and only +main():void in methods ????

Comment: yeah.. whats the big deal here.. does not matters whether or not your class contain any attributes or not.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it actually doesn't matter.

As long you are not generating interaction diagrams or any sort of execution out of this, having main in a diagram does not add any value except quick navigation to the main entry point (if possible).

The class containing the main should typically be (mostly...) empty containing only the main.

I tend to not have every detail in such diagrams since displaying a whole architecture on class level is rarely a good idea anyway. And main would be such a detail.

However this is only my point of view.